# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Apartment is not mapped [from Apartment]

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have springboot rest appplication with Hibernate and MySQL. I have this error:

> nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Apartment is not
> mapped [from Apartment]

But I dont know where I have a mistake. I have two tables: Apartments and Residents in DB. But now I try only getAllApartments() method. I use Intellij and I even checked my DB in her. And I have little picture near my Entity class, where I have correct data source. And I think that I checked names my class and fields.

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Apartments")
public class Apartment {

@Column(name = "apartment_id")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer apartmentId;

@Column(name = "apartment_number"
private Integer apartmentNumber;

@Column(name = "apartment_class")
private String apartmentClass;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH},
        mappedBy = "apartment")
List<Resident> residentList;
```

My DAO method:

```
@Repository
public class ApartmentDAOImpl implements ApartmentDAO {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Apartment> getAllApartment() {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Apartment");
    List<Apartment> apartmentList = query.getResultList();
    return apartmentList;
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApartmentController {

@Autowired
ApartmentService apartmentService;

@GetMapping("/apartments")
public List<Apartment> getAllApartments() {
    List<Apartment> apartmentList = apartmentService.getAllApartment();
    return apartmentList;
}
```

I also have service layer without any logic.
My property.file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/correct_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=projuser
spring.datasource.password=projuser
```

Give me advice, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, As I used multi module application, Hibernate or Spring didn't see my Entity.

And I clearly indicated my Entity class with `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.punko.entity"})` under my SpringBootApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.punko")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.punko.entity"})
public class SpringBootApplicationConfig {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplicationConfig.class, args);
}
```